# Shopify Looping Over JSON Metafield Arrays

Tags: json, shopify, liquid

For some reason, I can't access an array within a JSON metafield.. I've tried the other StackOverflow answers, and I'm using value, etc. but just can't figure it out, here's my metafield:

product.metafields.artist.releases

with a value of:

```
{
  "releases": [
   { 
    "id": 0,
    "releaseName": "lofi 1",
    "coverArt": "",
    "releaseLink": “”
},
 { 
"id": 1,
    "releaseName": " lofi 2",
    "coverArt": "",
    "releaseLink": “”
  }
]}
```

(which formats to: `"{\"releases\":[{\"id\":0,\"releaseName\":\"lofi 1\",\"coverArt\":\"\",\"releaseLink\":“”},{\"id\":1,\"releaseName\":\"lofi 2\",\"coverArt\":\"google.com\",\"releaseLink\":“”}]}"`)

and I'm using this in the product.custom.liquid:

```
{{ product.metafields.artist.releases.value }}
  
{% assign releases = product.metafields.artist.releases.value %}
  
  {% for release in releases.releases %}
  
    {{ release.releaseName }}
  
  {% endfor %}
```

the first one shows up fine, and if I assign it and do `{{ releases }}` it shows up fine as well so I know the assignment is working, but I can't forloop over it (mind you that the first object in the JSON is also called releases (I've also tried renaming it all to unique names just in case and that didn't help))

Comment: Strange... I have an extremely deeply nested JSON metafield on my test shop that I can deep-loop over without issue...  

Comment: Huh. Very weird - My old metafield from when json_string first became a thing works exactly as expected, but when I make a new metafield to test this I can't get it to work. Will have to dig into this more later, but it looks like maybe Shopify changed something somehow that makes new metafields less effective

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Liquid is not going to work on JSON like this. If you want to iterate through an array of JSON objects, use Javascript.

Comment: I was really hoping that wouldn't be the answer but sure enough, after tinkering around, that's what did it.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason when it is a multidimensional JSON array it acts weird. There is a simple fix for it, just add (-) at the end of your assigned variable:

```
{%- assign releases = product.metafields.artist.releases.value -%}
  
  {% for release in releases.releases %}
  
    {{ release.releaseName }}
  
  {%- endfor -%}
```

Hope it solves your problem like it did mine!

Answer (score 0):

As lov2code points out by adding (-) it trims the output for any unnecessary white space, which enables you to traverse the JSON array.